# LSApplicationQueriesSchemes Xcode 13 or iOS15 BUG?

Tags: ios15, xcode13, lsapplicationqueriesschemes

I use "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" in the project Info.plist, which contains 219 url schemes.

I use the urlscheme contained in this file to determine if an app is installed on our user's phone, which worked fine before iOS15, but recently I had a problem after submitting an app update using xcode13, when I went to check if an app was installed, it prompted me "-canOpenURL:failed for URL: "xxxx://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme xxxx".

[image]

I have added xxxx to the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, but I still get this error, I tested changing the location or reducing the number of urlscheme included in the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and found that The first 35 or so of the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes are working fine, and the first 35 or so after that will prompt this error. I don't know if this is a bug in xcode13 or a problem with ios15, it's still not right.

This problem only appears on phones upgraded with iOS15

Comment: I found this problem with xcode13 run on my iPhone, but not with xcode12, so I went back to xcode12 for now to package and upload IPA.

Comment: I found this problem with xcode13 run on my iPhone, but not with xcode12, so I went back to xcode12 for now to package and upload IPA.

Answer (score 10):

> Apps linked on or after iOS 15 are limited to a maximum of 50 entries in the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl?language=objc

Comment: Thx) How could I miss this change? 
The Russian National System of Payment Cards abused this feature a little. We have to include more than a thousand entries in this array to be able check the bank apps available for opening. Now this feature is broken(